# Kernel memory dump size Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I know the size of the kernel memory dumps depends on the amount of kernel memory allocated and the drivers loaded.  On systems with more RAM, it is reasonable to expect that the dump file will be larger.
What is the limit of kernel dumps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its reasonable unless you're getting the dump early in the boot process. Otherwise you will get a dump of the whole physical memory that was used. Linux kernel usually uses almost all memory available (if it's not needed for anything else, it will use it as cache) so dumps will be larger.